# If $Y_i$ are the irr. components of $Y$, then $\overline{Y_i}$ are the irr. componens of $\overline{Y}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Got a real dumb question for ya.  Suppose $Y$ is a subset of a topological space with irreducible components $Y_1, ... , Y_n$.  Then $\overline{Y_1}, ... , \overline{Y_n}$ should be the irreducible components of $\overline{Y}$, and they are all distinct.  Why is this?

Certainly the $\overline{Y_i}$ are irreducible.  I don't understand why $\overline{Y_i}$ is still a maximal irreducible subset of $\overline{Y}$, or why the $\overline{Y_i}$ should be distinct if the $Y_i$ are.  I would appreciate a hint on this.

Note this is not the same question as
[If $Y$ has irreducible components $Y_1, \cdots, Y_n$, then the $\overline{Y_i}$ are the irreducible components of $\overline{Y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65685/if-y-has-irreducible-components-y-1-cdots-y-n-then-the-overliney-i) because I am confused on a different part.

Comment: Hi, I think I've encountered this question before, but can't remember where. Do you mind providing a bit of context?

Comment: This result is on the first page of Borel's *Linear Algebraic Groups*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $\bar Y=\cup_j P_j$ where $P_i$ are irreducible components. You have $Y_i=\cup_j Y_i\cap P_j$. Note that $P_i$ are closed subsets of the closed set $\bar Y$ so $Y_i\cap P_j$ is closed in $Y$ since $Y_i$ is irreducible, there exists $j_i$ such that $Y_i\cap P_{j_i}=Y_i$. Let $Y_{j_1},...Y_{j_l}$ the connected components of $Y$ contained in $P_j$, since $P_j$ is closed, $\bar Y_{j_l}\subset P_j$ so $P_j=\cup \bar Y_{j_l}$. Since $P_j$ is irreducible, there exists $l$ such that $P_j=\bar Y_{j_l}$. Suppose that $P_j=\bar Y_{j_l}=\bar Y_{j_m}$. Remark that since $Y_{j_l}$ is closed, $Y_{j_l}=F_l\cap Y$ where $F_l$ is a closed subset. $F_l\cap  P_j$ is also a closed subset of $\bar Y$ which contains $Y_{j_l}$, since $\bar Y_{j_l}=P_j$ we deduce that $F_l \cap P_j=P_j$ thus $Y_{j_l}\cup Y_{j_m} \subset F_l\cap Y=Y_{j_l}$. This implies $Y_{j_l}=Y_{j_m}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  On the fourth line, why is $P_j \subseteq \cup \bar{Y_{j_l}}$?  I only see the other containment.

Comment: And on the last line, why is $Y_{j_m} \subseteq F_l \cap Y$?

Comment: $cl(A\cup B)=cl(A)\cup cl(B)$ for the first so the closure of $Y$ is the union of the closure of its irreducible component.

Comment: For the second, $F_l\cap P_j$ is a closed subset of $P_j$ which contains the dense subset $Y_{j_l}$ so $F_l\cap P_j=P_j$ and since $Y_{j_m}\subset P_j$ you can conclude.

Comment: I am still confused, but I'm accepting your answer.  I'm going to ask a new question.